# parseerror when getting XML via jQuery AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery

I want to pull an RSS feed via jQuery AJAX, but every time I do, I get a parsererror. My feed is relatively complex (using CDATA and custom namespaces), so I tried stripping down the document returned (along with a million other combinations), but even with an extremely simple document, it still fails. This is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ...,
    dataType: 'xml',

    success: function(xml) {
        ...
    },

    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        showError('an unknown error occurred while trying to fetch the feed: ' + xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Console output:

```
status: parsererror
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>title</title>
        <link>link</link>
        <description>desc</description>

        <lastBuildDate>build date</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>gen</generator>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: What's the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: You didn't show the url but is it possible that you're trying to make a cross domain request (which is impossible) and that's why it's failing?

Comment: What is the original xml file look like and what does error varable contain.

Comment: Yep, my server didn't automatically set the Content-Type header. Thanks!

Comment: @Chandra you should put you comment in the form of an answer so it can be accepted for future readers (and points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to serve the document with a `Content-Type` header of `application/rss+xml` or `text/xml`.