# IE JQuery ajax parseerror on local xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

In IE, JQuery is giving me a parseError when I'm trying to read a local XML file. Hoping someone might be able to spot it. Code works fine in FF

Jquery in question

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: settings.PresentationLocation,
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    contentType : 'application/xml',
    success: function(xml){
        //Setup the slides
        $(xml).find('slide').each(function(){
            //Create the slide
            obj.append('<div class="slide"><div class="slideTitle">'+ $(this).find('title').text() +'</div><div class="slideContent">'+ $(this).find('content').text() +'</div></div>');
        });

        totalSlides = obj.children('.slide').size();

        //Hide all the slides
        obj.children('.slide').hide();
    },

    error: function(xmlReq, status, errorMsg){
        console.log("Error Message: "+ errorMsg);
        console.log("Status: "+ status);
        console.log(xmlReq.responseText);

        throw(errorMsg);
    }
});
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slides>
    <slide>
        <title>Slide 3</title>
        <content>Hi there</content>
    </slide>
</slides>
```

Comment: Syntax looks good to me.  Did you test this using developer tools in ie8?  have any more specifics on the error it's giving you?  If you can't put breakpoints in there I'd add alerts so you can see exactly where it's erring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an Ideal Solution but it works:

I quickly found out that I am not the only one having this problem:

[google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Jquery+XML+parseerror&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) , [JQuery Bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6916) , [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011076/parseerror-when-getting-xml-via-jquery-ajax)

and everything I seem to read points to how IE reads and parses XML. Found a clever solution reading the comments here:

[blog](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-makes-parsing-xml-easy) see comment #28

This still didn't work. After some playing with the ajax function alittle I found that if I removed the dataType, in addition to the comment #28 in the blog post, everything worked across browsers.

Final code looks like:

```
//Retrieve our document
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: settings.PresentationLocation,
    success:function(results){
        var xml = methods.parseXML(results);

        $(xml).find('slide').each(function(){
            //Create the slide
            obj.append('<div class="slide"><div class="slideTitle">'+ $(this).find('title').text() +'</div><div class="slideContent">'+ $(this).find('content').text() +'</div></div>');
        });

        totalSlides = obj.children('.slide').size();

        //Hide all the slides
        obj.children('.slide').hide();
    },
    error: function(xmlReq, status, errorMsg){
        var errMsg = settings.PresentationLocation + " : "+ errorMsg ;
        throw(errMsg);
    }
});
```

where methods.parseXML is defined as

```
parseXML : function(xmlFile){
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        //IE
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(xmlFile);
        return doc;
    } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xmlFile, 'text/xml');
    }

    return "";
}
```