# Errori in displaying xml rest data using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Hy guys,I'm trying to display some xml data on a HTML page,I send my REST request and take the response using ajax but when I attach the elements on the DOM I obtain "undefined". here is the xml document

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <cities>
       <city>
           <cityPK>
               <name>Milano</name>
               <region>Lombardia</region>
           </cityPK>
     </city>
       <city>
        <cityPK>
              <name>Roma</name>
             <region>Lazio</region>
        </cityPK>
       </city>
   </cities> `
```

ant this is the code with the call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "xml",
     url: "http://localhost:8080/RestService/webresources/entities.city",
     success: function(xml){
        var city;
        $(xml).find("cityPK").each(function(){
            city = $(this).attr("name"); 
            console.log(city);
            $("#city").append(city+ "<br />");
         });
     }
    });
});
```

I know that probably the problem is because of the asynchronous operation,but I can't fix that.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Verify the page is served as xml. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011076/parseerror-when-getting-xml-via-jquery-ajax?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Where do I have to put this header?in the xml page that the server returns to me? I've put that header in the ajax call but it still does not working. @colecmc